# [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded

Tags: vue.js, store, quasar-framework

I get the following warning which causes that when I open this route the component takes a while to load and then the menu remains bugged. *[Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function*. What I suspect is that it may be because we store the data in a store variable:

Here is the front-end code in which I call the store and paint a rangeBar graph:

```
<template>
    <q-page>
      <div class="q-pa-md">
        <VueApexCharts
          v-if="!adquisicionStore.loading"
          type="rangeBar"
          height="200" 
          :options="chartOptions" 
          :series="chartSeries"
        />
      </div>
    </q-page>
 </template>

<script setup>
  import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
  import { useAdquisicion } from "../stores/main";
  import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
  
  const adquisicionStore = useAdquisicion();
  
  const chartSeries = ref([
    {
      name: 'horno1',
      data: [],
    }
  ]);
  
  const chartOptions = {
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        barHeight: '20%'
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 1
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
  };  
  
  onMounted(async () => {
    await adquisicionStore.loadHornoMarcha();
    updateChartSeries();
  });
  
  const updateChartSeries = () => {
    // Make sure adquisicionStore.hornoMarcha is an array of data
    chartSeries.value[0].data = adquisicionStore.hornoMarcha;
  }
  </script>
```

And this is the store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAdquisicion = defineStore('adquisicion', {
  state: () => ({
    hornoMarcha: [],
    loading: true
  }),

  actions: {

      async loadHornoMarcha() {
        try {
          const responseHorMar = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/horno-marcha');
          if (responseHorMar.status === 200) {
            this.hornoMarcha = responseHorMar.data;
            this.loading = false;
          } else {
            console.error('Error al obtener datos: Respuesta no válida');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error);
        }
      },

  },
  
});
```

I was hoping that the page would load quickly and when opening the menu it wouldn't crash.

Comment: Could you please add the template?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's it @Smileek

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening in the code you provided? The warning is pretty clear, if you mutate something that is being watched or is reactive and on it's turn it mutates another item which also mutates the first item, so the second one is going to get mutated so the first one is getting..... You get the point it is an infinite loop...

Comment: Yes, If the error occurs on the line "chartSeries.value[0].data = adquisicionStore.hornoMarcha;" This is shown by the error itself when expanding in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the apexcharts plugin and how it treats arrays. The solution was to put toRaw in :series. To remove reactivity.

```
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div class="q-pa-md">
      <VueApexCharts
        type="rangeBar"
        :height="200"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="toRaw(chartSeries)"
      />
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue3-apexcharts';
import { useAdquisicion } from "../stores/example-store";
import { ref, onMounted, toRaw } from "vue";

const adquisicionStore = useAdquisicion();

const chartSeries = ref([]); // Ahora es un array vacío para los datos

const chartOptions = {
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: true,
        barHeight: '20%'
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 1
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
  };

const fetchHornoMarcha = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await adquisicionStore.loadHornoMarcha();
    console.log
    // Asigna los datos a chartSeries
    chartSeries.value = [{
      data: response
    }];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al cargar datos:", error);
  }
};

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchHornoMarcha();
});

</script>

<style scoped>
#time-chart {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```